# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, sweetalert2

I'm creating a laravel SPA and I'm using vue.js as a framework. I'm adding a sweetalert package in my project but whenever i use the `toast` function it gets me an error. I tried using other functions like `swal.fire` and it works except for `toast.fire`. Can someone help me with this? Here are some of my codes.

app.js

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
import moment from 'moment'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueProgressBar from 'vue-progressbar'
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

window.Form = Form;
window.swal = swal;
window.toast = toast;
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)


const toast = swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000
  });


Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
    color: 'rgb(143, 255, 199)',
    failedColor: 'red',
    height: '2px'
  })

const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default },
    { path: '/profile', component: require('./components/Profile.vue').default},
    { path: '/users', component: require('./components/Users.vue').default}
  ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
  })

  Vue.filter('upText', function(text){
    return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  });

  Vue.filter('myDate', function(created){
    return moment(created).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
  });


Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default);
Vue.component('profile', require('./components/Profile.vue').default);
Vue.component('users', require('./components/Users.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Users.vue

```js
<template>
//html codes
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
            users: {},
                form: new Form({
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    type: '',
                    bio: '',
                    photo: '',
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
            loadUsers(){
                axios.get("api/user").then(( {data }) => (this.users = data.data));
            },
            createUser(){
                this.$Progress.start();
                this.form.post('api/user');
                toast.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'User Created',
                position: 'top-end',
                })
                this.$Progress.finish();
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
            this.loadUsers();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point this line runs, `toast` will be `undefined`:

```js
window.toast = toast;
```

Note that the line `const toast = swal.mixin({` comes later. You would need to write these lines the other way around.

Personally I wouldn't expose these directly on `window` in the first place. Either import them as required or add them to the Vue prototype:

```js
Vue.prototype.$toast = toast
```

You'd then use it by calling `this.$toast.fire` in your components.

Comment: it gets me and error of `"ReferenceError: $this is not defined"` sir

Comment: @Vince I've updated my answer to be more explicit. The main problem is that those two lines are the wrong way around. You must have the `const toast` line before the `window.toast` line. Given I made multiple suggestions it's difficult for me to know exactly what you tried to get that error.

Comment: Ohh i see, thats why I keep getting the error. Now it works!! I just put the `window.toast = toast` after the `const toast` method. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `toast.fire` in then event of `axios.post` as below,

```
createUser(){
  this.$Progress.start();
  axios.post('api/user', this.form).then(response => {
     toast.fire({
     type: 'success',
     title: 'User Created',
     position: 'top-end',
    })
    this.$Progress.finish();
  }).catch(error => {
    this.$Progress.finish();
  });
```

You can handle success and failure and show toast messages `.then` and `.catch` event respectively.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Haven't you imported toast in app.js?

Comment: yes sir. Ive figured it out. I should put `window.toast` after `const.toast` like @skirtle said. Thanks for your answer sir.

Comment: Great to hear that. Keep Coding! :D